# INSERT INTO command for type varchar(100) not working?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into a table in MySQL, and it is not working. I have two columns, call them A and B, in table x, which are both of type varchar(100) and have no indexes or restrictions. If I type

```
INSERT INTO x (A) VALUES("testval")
```

then it works fine, but if I type

```
INSERT INTO x (B) VALUES("testval")
```

it gives me an error:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'B) VALUES ("testval")' at
>   line 1

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the actual name of B?

Comment: Error 1064 pops out (among the other cases) when you're trying to use a reserved word as column name.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this

```
INSERT INTO `x` (`B`) VALUES ('testval')
```